# Regular expression for finding html tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a function, which will find each substring in string, where substring is some html tag, for example

`<li>`

But my regular expression don't work and i can't finde my mistake.

```
    $str = 'hello brbrbr <li> hello</li> <li>how are you?</li>';
    $items = preg_match_all('/(<li>\w+<\/li>)', $str, $matches);
```

$items must be an array of the desired substrings

Comment: `\w` is any word character, you have space there, maybe adding `\s` will be sufficient.

Comment: Oh, yes, expression is not closed correctly as well. Go to https://regex101.com/ and play with it

Comment: without space i also have 0 sublines in $items

Comment: Thank You, now i have correct expression (<li>\w+<\/li>), but i still have just a count of substring and this function found only first one

Comment: Consider using DOMDocument to parse and manipulate HTML or XML tags. Do not reinvent the wheel with Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using DOMDocument to parse and manipulate HTML or XML tags. Do not reinvent the wheel with Regex.

```
$str = 'hello brbrbr <li> hello</li> <li>how are you?</li>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$li = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
$value = $li->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $value;
```

> ' hello'

---

Or if you want to iterate over all

```
foreach($li as $item)
    echo $item->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
```

> ' hello'
> 'how are you?'

Answer (score 0):

Markus' answer is correct but in case you just want the fast and dirty regex one, here it is:

```
$str = 'hello brbrbr <li> hello</li> <li>how are you?</li>';
preg_match_all('/(<li>.+<\/li>)/U', $str, $items);
```

`U` makes it ungreedy.